# Cursor running indefinitely

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I wrote a simple cursor in SQL like below.Here i am expecting that it will fetch all the rows from test and as per the row count,hard coded values will be added in test2 table.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR customers is
    SELECT * FROM test;
BEGIN
  OPEN customers;
  LOOP
    insert into test2 values (2, 3, 3);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE customers;
END;
/
```

When I am executing it in sql prompt,it's running indefinitely.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I hope that this is a learning exercise and not something that you're trying to do in production code? Because in reality, you'd never write this as a loop through a cursor. Instead, you'd do: `insert into test2 select 2, 3, 3 from test;` (which you could then put into a pl/sql procedure if you needed to).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FOR LOOP`:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR customers IS
     SELECT * FROM test;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN customers
  LOOP
     insert into test2 values (2, 3, 3);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

or you need to add `EXIT CONDITION` becuase your loop is (indefinite):

```
DECLARE  
  CURSOR customers is
    SELECT * FROM test;

  l_customer customers%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN customers;
  LOOP
    FETCH customers INTO l_customer;
    EXIT WHEN customers%NOTFOUND;

    insert into test2 values (2, 3, 3);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE customers;
END;
/
```

**EDIT:**

As [**Lalit Kumar B**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33670726/3989608) mentioned in the comment, you can use:

```
BEGIN
   FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM test)
   LOOP
       insert into test2 values (2, 3, 3);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

For more info read [**Working with Cursors by Steven Feuerstein**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html)

Comment: Your first anonymous block which uses an explicit cursor, and then uses a for loop could be done in one step using a **CURSOR FOR LOOP**. `FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM test) LOOP...`

Answer (score 3):

I would rather avoid using an **explicit cursor** and use a **cursor for loop**.

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN
  (SELECT * FROM test
  )
  LOOP
    <do something>
    INSERT INTO test2 VALUES ...;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Remember, a loop would do the insert **row-by-row** a.k.a. **slow-by-slow**.

As @Boneist mentioned, there is a reason why the `cursor for loop` is better over the explicit cursor. In the recent Oracle versions, it is optimized in a better way by doing a `bulk collect limit 100` internally.

But, it's not just about **bulk collecting**, we are dealing with the **operations** we would subsequently do on the array that we have **fetched** incrementally. We could further improve the performance by using **FORALL** statement along with **BULK COLLECT**.

IMO, the best would be do it in pure **SQL** using `INSERT INTO table SELECT..`. There are lot of other factors, but it wouldn't be in the scope of OP's question.

Comment: "You could use BULK COLLECT to improve the performance." <--- I hate this response to the slow-by-slow approach; mainly because usually (as in the OP's example) you don't need a cursor at all, and partly because Oracle optimises a cursor-for-loop to do bulk collect limit 100 behind-the-scenes anyway.

Comment: @Boneist .. You explained exactly why I prefer `cursor for loop` over an `explicit cursor`. The other part regarding `BULK COLLECT`, OP is doing a **row-by-row** insert, which could be improved further. I agree with you, in recent versions the `cursor for loop` does a bulk collect limit 100`. What I have seen in recent versions is that the bulk limit 100 in cursor for loop is good, but bulk fetch along with **FORALL** is even better. I would reword my answer when I get time. IMO, I would rather do a plain insert. Thanks for bringing this up :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the way your using cursors is not correct. In below i have edited your code.. And you need to add exit condition for terminating loop.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR customers is
    SELECT * FROM test;
   cus2  customers%rowtype;
BEGIN
  OPEN customers;
  LOOP
  FETCH customers INTO cus2;
  EXIT WHEN customers%NOTFOUND;
    insert into test2 values (2, 3, 3);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE customers;
END;
/
```

Modify the above block based on your requirement.

Comment: its giving me `the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed`

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta i have updated my query please check now.

Comment: Thanks @Tarun for quick response.